# Google Cloud Storage: where is the documentation describing the parameters (suffix) w, h, -p etc

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

### The case

By default, google cloud storage serves pictures sized by 512xYYY.

I would like to retrieve the picture in different sizes depending my needs (full, thumb ...)

[A python function](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions) states that suffixing an url generated by get_serving_url with 's=' would resize the picture. **Unfortunately it doesn't work.**

Please try with my [test case, this is a world map](http://lh4.ggpht.com/lefjZJdvOR45wpUorc5ewNVQ-BRcq-zKNNZTrouAZMHh2R_euf86ks62-nbh-ipzHKXA8YZ_APfZZ-nfOWArzWSFTWo) originally sized 2130 × 1204 and weighted 3,6 Mb.

### The Solution but I need to find the related documentation

I have found that suffixing pictures on G+ with '=w469-h281-p' do the job but **I don't know where to find the documentation describing how this works.**

I tested different cases and I start to figure out what the '-p' suffix means but I wonder if other suffixes are available

### Example that works from a random G+ picture

[Picture stored on Google server taken from G+ resized by 469x281](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/JJqdqhnOXvdcgZCM9UZbWZkaQV5_pU1gdjl%E2%80%A6EOaXKXJVGB347CnsDV13KNwwkj2zX31hsfCdJbft2d0lQcfhH8xZO81-K9daNA=w469-h281-p), look at the suffix '=w469-h281-p'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have misread the [document you refer to](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions), it does not say to append **s=** to the URL, it says to append the string **=sNN** where **NN** is the required size in pixels, e.g. **=s100**

Comment: @lanGSY you are right, you have answered part of the question; I have misread the doc.

But, I am still searching for the documentation regarding the other parameters : w, h, -p ...